Importing a CMake project into CodeLite (again)
This question was answered earlier.
But now CMake says that "support of extra generators is deprecated" and that I should use cmake-file-api. I can't figure out how to use it.
The previous solution still works, but according to CMake warning, this option will be removed in future releases.
Does any know what to do when this will happen?

The different IDEs should update themselves to use cmake-file-api instead of letting CMake generate the solution.

https://docs.codelite.org/plugins/cmake/

[Feature Request]: Generation of Codelite project from CMake is deprecated since version 3.27
